# Open sets in $n+m$ dimensions is the cartesian product of open sets in $n$ and $m$ dimensions

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

I'm considering the open sets of $\mathbb{R}^{n+m}$. I'm trying to show that any open set $Q \subseteq \mathbb{R}^{n+m}$, can be written as a cartesian product $Q = U \times V$, where $U$ is open in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ and $V$ is open in $\mathbb{R}^{m}$ (here I am making the identification $\mathbb{R}^{n+m} \cong \mathbb{R}^{n} \times \mathbb{R}^{m}$).

Here is my proof:

For an open set $Q$, there exist sets $U \subset \mathbb{R}^{n}$ and $V \subset \mathbb{R}^{m}$ such that $Q = U \times V$ (since $\mathbb{R}^{n+m} \cong \mathbb{R}^{n} \times \mathbb{R}^{m}$).

Take any point $u \in U$. Take an arbitrary point $v \in V$. Then $(u,v) \in U \times V = Q$. Since $(u,v) \in Q$, which is open, there exists an $r>0$ such that $B_{r}((u,v))_{n+m} \subseteq Q$. (the subscript $n+m$, means I am considering the open ball in $n+m$ dimensions).

Consider next the set $B_{r}(u)_{n}$. Take a point $a \in B_{r}(u)_{n}$. Then we have $||u - a||_{n} < r$.

Now define the vector $(a,v)\in \mathbb{R}^{k+\ell}$. Then we find that:

$|| (a,v) - (u,v) ||_{n+m} = || (a-u,0) ||_{n+m} = || a-u ||_{n} < r$

Then we find that $(a,v) \in B_{r}((u,v))_{n+m} \subseteq U \times V$. Thus, $a \in U$, and we find that $B_{r}(u) \subseteq U$.

We see that for every $u \in U$, there exists an $r>0$ such that $B_{r}(u) \subseteq U$. Thus, $U$ is open.

By the same method, we find that $V$ is open.

Is my proof flawed? I am uncomfortable with taking the norm in different dimensions so freely.

Comment: The statement you're trying to prove isn't true. Consider an open ball in $\mathbb R^2 = \mathbb R \times \mathbb R$.

Comment: Is this really true? Consider an open disk in the plane. It does not appear to be a cartesian product of open sets on the line.  Do you mean that it is a *union* of such Cartesian products?

Comment: Your error becomes from the first line: $\{(x,x)\}\subset\mathbb{R}^2$, but it can't be written as $A\times B$ with $A,B\subset\mathbb{R}$

Comment: @sinbadh To be fair, the claim is about open sets and that set isn't open.

Comment: Yes @manthanomen, but the error that generates all is the first line. Indeed, if the first line would true, all the others arguments are true

Comment: @sinbadh Yes, the error is in the first line of the proof, but your example isn't a counterexample to what's claimed there.

Comment: This is a very silly mistake, and I can't believe it didn't occur to me. I'm trying to prove that the metric topology on $\mathbb{R}^{n+m}$ coincides with the product topology on $\mathbb{R}^{n} \times \mathbb{R}^{m}$, so I will use the the union of such Cartesian products as you say.

Comment: What you probably want to do is to prove that projections are open mappings.